In ia-32e mode, why i can't to read/write the address its higher than 4gb?
hello I'm a beginner of assembly language so need some help... I tried to write a 64-bit x86 bootloader (MBR), after running it looks like no problem. but when I add some about "accessing memory address higher than 4gb" operation to the code, I found these read and write operations doesn't work. (has no effect.) I feel very confused.
for specific phenomena, please refer to the code block marked "test4gb" in the code below.
if we change the number a of PAGE_L3_2 to above 4GB of space, the screen will not display 'w'.
Thanks for your help!!! Grateful!!!
the following is my code... Using NASM
org 0x7c00

flatcode equ 0x0008
flatdata equ 0x0010

section .text

[bits 16]

bspstart:

    cli

    xor ax,ax
    mov ds,ax

    lgdt [GDT_DESC]

    in al,92h
    or al,00000010b
    out 92h,al

    mov ax,0
        mov ds,ax
    mov es,ax
    mov si,PML4_TABLE0      ;copy PML4
    mov di,00001000h
    mov cx,PML4_TABLE_END - PML4_TABLE0     
    cld     
    rep movsb

    mov ax,0
    mov ds,ax
    mov es,ax
    mov si,PAGE_DIRECTROIC_POINTER_TABLE0           ;copy page-directoric-pointer-table
    mov di,00002000h
    mov cx,PAGE_DIRECTROIC_POINTER_TABLE_END - PAGE_DIRECTROIC_POINTER_TABLE0   
    cld 
    rep movsb

    mov ax,0
    mov ds,ax
    mov es,ax
    mov si,PAGE_DIRECTROIC_TABLE0   ;copy page-directroic_table
    mov di,00003000h
    mov cx,PAGE_DIRECTROIC_TABLE_END - PAGE_DIRECTROIC_TABLE0       
    cld     
    rep movsb                          
                                      
    mov ax,0
    mov ds,ax
    mov es,ax
    mov si,PAGE_L3_0        ;copy page-table
    mov di,00004000h
    mov cx,PAGE_L3_END - PAGE_L3_0  
    cld     
    rep movsb                          

    mov eax,00000001h           ;enable ia-32 no-paging
    mov cr0,eax

    jmp dword flatcode:bspprotect

[bits 32]

bspprotect:

    mov ax,flatdata
    mov ds,ax

    mov eax,00000020h           ;set cr4.pae
    mov cr4,eax

    mov eax,00001000h            ;load cr3 register
    mov cr3,eax

    mov ecx,0c0000080h
    rdmsr                       ;set ia32.efer msr
    mov eax,00000100h
    wrmsr

    mov eax,80000001h
    mov cr0,eax                 ;enable paging

    jmp dword flatcode:bspia32e

[bits 64]

bspia32e:
    
    lgdt [RGDT_DESC]        ;load long-mode discriptor
    
    mov rcx,0x1b
    mov rbp,0x1

s:  mov byte [rbp],1fh
    inc rbp
    inc rbp

    loop s

    mov byte [0x0],'I'
    mov byte [0x2],'A'
    mov byte [0x4],'3'
    mov byte [0x6],'2'
    mov byte [0x8],'e'
    mov byte [0xa],' '
    mov byte [0xc],'M'       ;draw screen
    mov byte [0xe],'o'
    mov byte [0x10],'d'
    mov byte [0x12],'e'
    mov byte [0x14],'!'
    mov byte [0x16],' '
    mov byte [0x18],'6'
    mov byte [0x1a],'4'

    mov rcx,2000
    mov rbp,0x1d

s2: mov byte [rbp],3fh
    inc rbp
    inc rbp

    loop s2

test4gb:
    mov al,'w'
    mov byte [0x2000],al
    mov byte bl,[0x2000]        ;test access to memory addresses higher than 4gb
    mov byte [0x20],bl

    jmp $

PML4_TABLE0:

    dq 0000000000002001h

PML4_TABLE_END:

PAGE_DIRECTROIC_POINTER_TABLE0:

    dq 0000000000003001h
    
PAGE_DIRECTROIC_POINTER_TABLE_END:

PAGE_DIRECTROIC_TABLE0:

    dq 0000000000004001h            

PAGE_DIRECTROIC_TABLE_END:

PAGE_L3_0:

    dq 00000000000b8001h            

PAGE_L3_1:

    dq 00000000c0000001h

PAGE_L3_2:

    dq 000000000a000001h
    ;dq 0000000a00000001h  <-- doesn't work

PAGE_L3_3:

    dq 0000000000000001h

PAGE_L3_4:

    dq 0000000000000001h

PAGE_L3_5:

    dq 0000000000000001h

PAGE_L3_6:

    dq 0000000000000001h

PAGE_L3_7:

    dq 0000000000007001h    ;Page table entry used as code 

PAGE_L3_END:

GDT:

    dq 0000000000000000h

GDT_FLAT_CODE:

    dq 00cf9a000000ffffh

GDT_FLAT_DATA:

    dq 00cf92000000ffffh

GDT_END:

GDT_DESC:

    dw GDT_END - GDT - 1
    dd GDT

RGDT:

    dq 0000000000000000h

RGDT_FLAT_CODE:

    dq 00af9a000000ffffh

RGDT_FLAT_DATA:

    dq 00af92000000ffffh

RGDT_END:

RGDT_DESC:

    dw RGDT_END - RGDT - 1
    dd RGDT

times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0

db 0x55
db 0xaa


Works here. How much memory do you have? Note that a00000000h is 40GB ...

As an addendum to what Jester said, likely the physical memory address mapped to 0x2000 doesn't exist and anytime you read it probably always returns 0xff and then you move the value 0xff to the screen rather than a w

Thanks for your answers, the problem is indeed here! My lack of sensitivity to 16-bit numbers caused me to ignore such rapid memory address growth... @Jester

Thanks for your answers, the problem is indeed here! My lack of sensitivity to 16-bit numbers caused me to ignore such rapid memory address growth... @MichaelPetch
